# How to read and write files from disk using the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am going to be working with very large files of data (many gigabytes). I will have to read these files and write to these files. Hence, I will not be able to rely on RAM to store the data, and will need to read and write the files from disk.

I am familiar with the `read_csv` and `to_csv` options that the pandas library provides.  However, I am not sure if the `read csv` function reads a file and then stores it on RAM or reads the files directly from disk.

What would be the best way to read and write files from disk using pandas?

Comment: look into read_hdf()

Answer (score 3):

`pandas.read_csv` will read the entire file into memory. If you only need particular columns, you can use the `usecols` argument to specify that subset of columns and pandas will only load those columns.

Since your file does not fit in memory, you could split the file on disk using [split](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) and perform all operations on the chunks.

An easy alternative is to use `read_csv` from [dask.dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) from the [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) library.

From the documentation:

`A Dask DataFrame is a large parallel dataframe composed of many smaller Pandas dataframes, split along the index. These pandas dataframes may live on disk for larger-than-memory computing on a single machine, or on many different machines in a cluster.`