# Python: Handling groupby on large dataset

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a file, like so,

```
ID,CLASS_ID,COURSE_FEE,COURSE_ID
1,9XG,500,3
2,07CWG,1000,6
3,9XG,150,6
4,07CWG,1500,6
5,016IRE,80,9
6,9XG,100,10
7,07CWG,500,6
```

I would like to get those `CLASS_IDs` that is having the greater `COURSE_ID` with respect to its `COURSE_FEE`. Also if a `CLASS_ID` is having same `COURSE_ID`, then the total sum of the corresponding `COURSE_FEE`s needs to be fetched.

So the expected output would be something like so,

```
ID,CLASS_ID,COURSE_ID,COURSE_FEE
6,9XG,10,100
5,016IRE,9,80
2,07CWG,6,3000
```

This is the script I created for this:

```
import pandas as pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('Inpt.txt', dtype={'CLASS_ID': str})
df['COURSE_ID_AGG'] = df.groupby(['CLASS_ID', 'COURSE_ID'])['CLASS_ID'].transform(pandas.Series.value_counts)
df['SUM'] = df.groupby(['CLASS_ID', 'COURSE_ID'])['COURSE_FEE'].transform('sum')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CLASS_ID', 'COURSE_ID'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['CLASS_ID', 'COURSE_ID', 'SUM'], ascending=[0, 0, 0])
df.drop(['COURSE_FEE', 'COURSE_ID_AGG'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'SUM': 'COURSE_FEE'})
df = df.groupby('CLASS_ID', as_index=False).nth(0)
df.to_csv('Op.txt', index=False)
```

The script is giving me expected output but for small inputs.

My input file actually contains 200 Million records and because of that my script throws an `OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION`.

Could any of you python veterans help a newbie in suggesting a way to handle such a large input on this script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pandas cannot handle 200 million records. Not unless you do one chunk at a time.

Comment: pd.read_csv reads the entire dataset into memory. Since this dataset does not fit into memory, you could try reading the data in chunks as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247560/how-to-read-and-write-files-from-disk-using-the-pandas-dataframe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @coldspeed: Could you explain me how I can do that and how to handle the groupbys on these chunks?. I'm very new to programming so please bear with me.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268804/4909087

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051210/avoiding-memory-issues-for-groupby-on-large-pandas-dataframe